# How to increase data transmission speed between cc2500 and cc2511?

Tags: rf

-I am using cc2500 at target side and cc2511 at host side.

-I want to transmit or receive data of 8Mb between this two chip.

-data rate set to 250 Kbps.

-My communication frequency is 2410.0 Mhz

- **So is that possible to transmit or receive data of 8 Mb within 10 Min using this cc IC?????**
- **what are the maximum time to take transmit or receive data ???**

Comment: Your code below (which should have been an edit) is doing a calibration among other things before sending 44 bytes and then for some reason sending 500 SFTX commands. It also has delays that probably aren't needed, to get that speed you'll probably need to have a good read of the datasheet and see what the minimum requirements are and probably also send larger packets.

Answer (score 1):

8 million bits in ten minutes is 13.33k bits per second. Shouldn't be a problem if your max throughput is 250k bits per second.

Max time depends on how far the tx and rx are from each other. More than a certain distance nothing will be received. Close together 8Mb will be sent in 32 seconds at  250k bps.

Comment: Important to note that this assumes 8Mb is in mega-bits, not the more common (when referring to data size) mega-bytes. It's also possible, if not likely, that the OP is referring to data that is 8 mebi-bytes (67,108,864 bits). Which any normal OS would call 8Mb. If that were the case, it's on the edge of possible (with overhead) that 250k bits per second would not be enough to get in under ten minutes.

Comment: @Samuel MB is megabytes Mb is megabits.

Comment: I don't disagree. But does the OP know that? After all, it should be MHz, not Mhz. I was pointing to the fact that this is a common confusion point, not that you were incorrect in any way.

Comment: @Samuel very true - you see "h" used a lot instead of "H". Sometimes you see "mebi" used instead of "mega" LOL (check your comment dude!!). However, if he's saying 250kbps and means 250kBps then 8MB at 250kBps is still 32 seconds!! If he's mixing up b and B for the same thing then he's a little careless and should read this conversation.

Comment: Mebi-bytes are a real thing, so are kibi-bytes. A kibibyte is 1024 bytes. A kilobyte conforms to SI and is 1000 bytes. Most operating systems still use kB to refer to 1024 bytes though, confusion compounded.

Comment: @Samuel Wow I never knew that - I'll confuse them at work on Monday with mebi bytes and kikibytes LOL

Comment: @sAm-Uel-I think you are English teacher LOL....